# Capture audio streams in real time client side

Tags: web-apps, audio, streaming

I'd like to capture my own audio streams from voice calls made using various communication SDKs/platforms. There are literally hundreds of these chat SDKs/platforms such as Zoom, Zendesk, MessageBird, Aircall, JustCall, Dixa, SendBird, etc.. then there are PBX cloud solutions as well, VoIP...

Some platforms/SDKs may offer an out-of-the-box solution to grab audio streams in real time, such as Twilio. I would assume that most do not offer this.

The software would have to be designed around what I can control, i.e my own application that is using the chat SDK/platform. Because I may not have access to the backend of the chat SDK/platform if they don't allow it in order to grab the audio streams in real time.

I currently have a node.js SDK that grabs any base64 audio stream that is able to be sent via WebSocket connection. This works for chat SDKs/platforms such as Twilio, which allow streams to be sent to a websocket server of your choice.

Any ideas or suggestions for software to use that grabs audio streams in real time from your own application?

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) can also be used for recording any audio playing on your computer. Please see the tutorial [here](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer.html). You should check the [developers forum](https://www.audacityteam.org/community/developers/) to see how to automate this via a plugin, etc.

Comment: Appreciate the response, however this won't work. It needs to capture the audio on the backend of the client side SDK.

Comment: In theory, since the code is available on https://github.com/audacity/audacity it may be possible. Best to ask on the forums https://github.com/audacity/audacity/issues   or  https://forum.audacityteam.org/ before ruling it out.

Answer (score 0):

What Platform?

[Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) can do anything along those lines on Mac.

On Windows, Voicemeeter have several products, from their virtual cable interconnect to the more elaborate '[banana](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/banana.htm)' or '[potato](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/potato.htm)' [don't blame me for the names;)

Comment: Appreciate the response, however this won't work. It needs to capture the audio on the backend of the client side SDK.

Comment: hmmm… interestingly, though I understand every word of "backend of the client side SDK" I have no clue what it means in practise, sorry.